# Jersey: How to find the final URL after redirection?

Tags: java, jersey, redirect

I am using the Jersey client API to request a URL. The first URL redirects Jersey to a second URL. The second URL redirects Jersey to a third URL, and so on. How do I find out the final URL Jersey ends up at without disabling redirection handling and manually processing the redirects myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed a bug report against Jersey 2.0: http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1611